# Add search field when add Answer in Django admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an `Answer` model in this field I have `answer_dependens_on`

```
model class Answer(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(
        "app.Question", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    answer_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    answer_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,
                                        decimal_places=4,
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    answer_dependens_on = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Answer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Answers'

    def __str__(self):
        return "answer={};  question={}".format(self.answer_title, self.question_id)
```

[image]

I want to add search in this field

Answer (score 0):

In admin.py file, define `answer_dependens_on` field as autocomplete_fields
and add `answer_title` field as searchable field

```
@admin.register(Answer)
class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    search_fields = ["answer_title"]
    autocomplete_fields = ["answer_dependens_on"]
```

for more details about [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields)